# How to change the background in XHTML pages

Tags: background, xhtml, inline-styles

I use Primefaces, version 4.0 and i would like to change the background of all pages in my web application. I tried:

```
<body style="background-image: url('..\\images\\balloons.jpg');">
```

as well as putting:

```
<body background="<http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Mufflon-02.jpg>">
```

but no background. Do you know how to set it up?
Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `background-image: url('../images/balloons.jpg')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example you give does not contain a [url](/questions/tagged/url) (it's more like a file address on your own computer) and the second isn't valid html, not least because the url is enclosed in triangle brackets.

You can use the inline style on the body tag if you want (your first example). The correct syntax is `<body style="background-image: url('/images/balloons.jpg');">` if there is indeed an image at that location.

The second would also work as `<body background="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Mufflon-02.jpg">`, but it's not good to be [hotlinking](/questions/tagged/hotlinking) to an image like that. Upload your background image to your website and link to that instead.

Comment: The second one works perfect but i really better to use the first one. I have an image in the directory F:\Project\workspace\MyProject\WebContent\resources\images\balloons.jpg but it does not work.

Comment: Where is your webpage saved? Do you upload this to some webspace on the Internet?

Comment: No, it is local, just on my PC.

Comment: What is the location of your webpage?

Comment: F:\Project\workspace\MyProject\WebContent\test.xhtml

Comment: In which case, `<body style="background-image: url('resources/images/balloons.jpg');">` should work on both your local machine and when you upload your project to the web; assuming you keep the same folder structure.

Comment: Thanks! I made it work using:  <body style="background-image: url('#{resource['images/balloons.jpg']}');">